# Is there a way to flatten an Array of Array type?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes in a type like:

```
type Input = [Array<string>, Array<number>, Array<boolean>];
```

It returns output in the form:

```
Array<[string, number, boolean]>
```

Effectively flattening the type out of the array.

---

Is there a way to achieve this with generics? My function signature at the moment looks like:

```
function foo<T extends Array<Array<unknown>>>(arrays: T) {

}
```

Assumedly, I need to apply some sort of transform onto T, what transform do I need?

Comment: Can you put some example data.

Comment: There's no data involved in this question. It's all about the types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type Unarrayify<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Array<infer E> ? E : T[K] };

type MyType = Unarrayify<[Array<number>, Array<string>, Array<boolean>]>; // [number, string, boolean]

function foo<T>(arrays: T): Array<Unarrayify<T>>() {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this work for tuple types aswell? `extends Array` doesn't work for non-arrays, for some reason `[1, 2]` doesn't extend array. Is there a type that includes types like `[1, 2]`, but isn't `Iterable`? `Iterable` doesn't have array properties on it like `.map`, so it ain't right here.

Comment: I believe there are a bit too many brackets in that function definition, no?

Comment: Update: I believe changing `extends Array` to `extends ReadonlyArray` was what I needed for that functionality. I was using `as const` to create fixed-type tuples and that was making it readonly.